# "A descriptive string set at run-time. Don't localize."?

Tags: safari

When I open Safari, in my Bookmarks tab it shows me a pop-up:

[image: A descriptive string set at run-time. Don't localize.]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an internal testing message for localization. Are you using a beta version of Safari? or have you in the past? It may be a case of resetting safari content if so.

Comment: Yosemite just showed me a notification to try out the new Safari, so I clicked it and that showed up at the bottom. I just tried to click Keep and Don't Keep, and neither button does anything, so it seems to just be a bug.